# Trying to set opacity for 1px line

Tags: css, html

I am trying to do the following:

```
border-bottom: 1px solid #00b4f5;
```

When I add `opacity: .8;` to the 1px line, it applies it to the entire `#name{}` as well.

I would only like the 1px line to have the opacity applied.

Comment: Use rgba() for **border color** instead of **hexcode**. Ex: border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,180,245,0.8) : Play with last value to set **opacity**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set the **`opacity`** it will affect the entire element, whereas using **`rgba()`** will apply to the specific property you set it to.

In **`rgb`**, **`#00b4f5`** equals to **`rgb(0, 180, 245)`**, so with **`opacity: .8`** your code will be:

```
.element {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 180, 245, .8);
}
```

---

**Note:** [Here](http://hex2rgba.devoth.com/) is a nice website to use to make your `hex2rgb` conversions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Use `rgba(255,0,0,0.8)` when color your border

```
div {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,0,0,0.8);
  background-clip: padding-box;               /* add if the element have a background */
}
```